# Can't connect to tomcat webservice

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

So I've been doing a java webservice in Eclipse in which I have launched on a localhost tomcat from Eclipse. This has worked very good as long as I've been connecting to the tomcat started from Eclipse.

However now I want to try deploy it on my tomcat separated from Eclipse but still on localhost. So I exported my web project to a .war file and deployed it with the tomcat manager app. However now I cant reach it from my client any longer. I'm running the tomcat on port 8080, just as my Eclipse tomcat did. BUT I can go to a reasource URL from my web browser and receive proper information, so the service is running(which the manager app is saying as well).

The client is a android device connected to the same network. The service fetches information from a MySQL database on the same machine. This connection worked fine before exporting it to war on my other tomcat

What am I doing wrong here? Just ask if you need any further information!

Comment: What errors are you getting when trying to connect? (sorry, deleted my previous comment because I saw your edit with clarification)

Comment: On client side it says the connection timed out

Comment: Are you sure you have the URL correct in your client?

Comment: Yes, it's the same as it was when running from eclipse. I can get response from browser on that URL

Comment: Do I need to any configurations that allow other connections from the same network for my tomcat?

Comment: When you try to access your webservice, is there any error message in your tomcat window? i mean is it displaying any errors?

Comment: Do you see any error in the log file `catalina.out` or in the file `localhost.<date>.log` located in the same directory ?

Comment: catalina.out says nothing strange, same with localhost.<date>.log. However my localhost_access_log only logs about my browser attempts to the service, so I guess there is something wrong with my client path after all?

Comment: @fathah, what is the tomcat window?

Comment: you are starting tomcat by running \bin\startup.bat right?

Comment: Nope, I'm running in windows enviroment if that has anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after testing I found it strange that I got connection time-outs and not something else. It also took at least 10 seconds before any feedback occurred. Sooo it felt like a firewall problem which indeed it was.

First I needed to portforward the tomcat port in my router to the machine ip that was hosting it. Then I remembered I had Windows firewall on that very machine which was also blocking conenctions on that port. So I allowed connections on tomcat port and BAM! It worked.

Thanks for all your comments, of course I should have thought about opening my ports before coming here.